# Can I pretty print a complicated string in R console?

Tags: r

I want to get the effect of `what I say is what I get`.

```
"b\" it\'s me \"ha ha\""->string
print(string)
[1] "b\" it's me \"ha ha\""
```

Can I pretty print the string in a simple way?
What I want to get it displayed in the screen is:

```
b "it's me "ha ha"
```

Comment: I don't understand this question. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try `cat`?

```
cat(string)

b" it's me "ha ha"
```